# How to make If Else run along other functions

Tags: javascript, function, backbone.js, procedural-programming

```
var time = 0;
function time(){
    setInterval(time++, 500);
    if (time > 1800){
        time = 0;
    }
    setInterval(alert("The time is" + time), 500);
}
```

I've tried to create a timing system based off a half second every 15 minutes.
Unfortunately I cannot test as it as the second `setInterval` does not run.

I suppose this is something due to the fact the code does not continue running as `setInterval` keeps looping.

I suppose the narrow question would be how do I get all three of those to run at once.

The broader would be how does one program object oriented?

Comment: You should name your variable and function different things. `time++` is very confusing in your example.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems with your code....

First, you have a variable named time, and a function named time...and that's going to cause no end of trouble for you.

Second, the first argument to `setInterval` must be a function (or a string, but I hesitate to even mention that because it's a bad idea and I don't want to encourage it).

Thirdly, unless you're actually calling `time()` somewhere later (you didn't show it in your code), neither of the `setInterval` calls will get executed.

Here's how you might re-write your code:

```
var _time = 0;
function time() {
    _time++;
    if(_time > 1800) _time = 0;    
    setTimeout(function() { alert('The time is ' + _time); }, 500);
}
setInterval(time, 900000);  // 900000 ms = 15 minutes
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and the extremely fast response but this failed to work. ALl this

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the underscores on the `_time` variables.  It's been corrected, and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to setInterval must be a function!  Like this:

```
var time = 0;
function time(){
    setInterval(time++, 500);
    if (time > 1800){
        time = 0;
    }
    setInterval(function() { alert("The time is" + time)}, 500);
}
```

You have the secondary problem that you are assigning `time` to zero, then assigning it to a function, then incrementing it (which sets it NaN), then comparing it to 1800 (which will fail).  I think you want two variables: `timeCounter` and `timeFunction`.

```
var timeCounter = 0;
function timeFunction(){
    timeCounter++;
    if (timeCounter > 1800){
        timeCounter = 0;
    }
    alert("The time is" + timeCounter);
    setInterval(timeFunction, 500);
}
```

But if you run this function, you'll be very sorry, because it will keep popping up alerts until you kill the window (in the half-second interval between pop-ups).

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly ,** 
 time is a variable  , time is a function ==> it is wrong.
  ===> REname your function .

**Secondly**:

setInterval (first, seconde) should have as first argument a function.

```
var time = 0;
function timefn(){
    setInterval(function() { time++}, 500);
    if (time > 1800){
        time = 0;
    }
    setInterval(function() { alert("The time is" + time)}, 500);
}
```

If you want a performed code by letting the name of function :

```
 function time(){
        setInterval(function() { time.time++}, 500);
        if (time.time > 1800){
            time.time = 0;
        }
        setInterval(function() { alert("The time is" + time.time)}, 500);
    }
    time.time = 0;
```

It is because function can be used as object > Thus, we add new attribute to `time` object(function) and we call it `time` also